# Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa. Trying to plot with tikz and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hey I am trying to compile the following Latex (minimal not working example)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{hdfs_logs.csv}
iteration,GD/CD,data,data_size,basis/chunk size,#basis/chunks,dedup #basis/chunks
0,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-25.log,413141404,127,3227668,2653695
1,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-05.log,377418163,127,6176248,5057417
2,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-14.log,379043438,127,9137525,7471653
3,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-06.log,407971604,127,12324804,10078357
4,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-31.log,325649983,127,14868945,12497466
5,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-01.log,697979040,127,20321907,17709829
6,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-mesos-01.log,1125510545,127,29114959,24421362
7,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-16.log,311133116,127,31545687,26325360
8,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-27.log,420281792,127,34829139,29016087
9,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-mesos-01.log,88368089,127,35519515,29383729
10,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-19.log,449586557,127,39031910,32289842
11,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-17.log,447704440,127,42529601,35180232
12,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-10.log,397436049,127,45634571,37698415
13,gd,files/hdfs_logs/HDFS.log,1577982906,127,57962563,50020476
14,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-11.log,367908511,127,60836849,52344531
15,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-20.log,429342641,127,64191089,55098658
16,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-23.log,437840376,127,67611717,57912426
17,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-09.log,418434394,127,70880736,60585993
18,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-02.log,409896876,127,74083056,63201232
19,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-30.log,324151612,127,76615491,65592999
20,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-07.log,441950547,127,80068230,68440749
21,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-08.log,423204337,127,83374514,71111739
22,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-13.log,423620342,127,86684048,73820147
23,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-32.log,50871010,127,87081478,74192578
24,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-18.log,458333837,127,90662212,77156397
25,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-21.log,438525916,127,94088196,79965402
26,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-26.log,421852834,127,97383922,82661302
27,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-15.log,348380332,127,100105644,84806117
28,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-29.log,400564914,127,103235058,87346793
29,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-22.log,438617352,127,106661757,90158102
30,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-28.log,426304072,127,109992258,92878451
31,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-03.log,444897046,127,113468017,95736769
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ymajorgrids,      
      xlabel=MB ingested into system,
      ylabel=MB stored in System
      ]
      \addplot table [x=iteration, y=iteration, col sep=comma] {hdfs_logs.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

But I get the error: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa` 
I have spend quite some time now trying to figure out what is wrong, but I cannot. Anyone who can spot my mistake? I am very confused with the error as well, as the csv is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` characters are special in TeX, they indicate parameters. One way to make your plot work is to remove them in the table (as they are not used here). A perhaps more elegant possibility is to use the `text special chars` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{hdfs_logs.csv}
iteration,GD/CD,data,data_size,basis/chunk size,#basis/chunks,dedup #basis/chunks
0,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-25.log,413141404,127,3227668,2653695
1,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-05.log,377418163,127,6176248,5057417
2,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-14.log,379043438,127,9137525,7471653
3,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-06.log,407971604,127,12324804,10078357
4,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-31.log,325649983,127,14868945,12497466
5,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-01.log,697979040,127,20321907,17709829
6,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-mesos-01.log,1125510545,127,29114959,24421362
7,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-16.log,311133116,127,31545687,26325360
8,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-27.log,420281792,127,34829139,29016087
9,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-mesos-01.log,88368089,127,35519515,29383729
10,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-19.log,449586557,127,39031910,32289842
11,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-17.log,447704440,127,42529601,35180232
12,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-10.log,397436049,127,45634571,37698415
13,gd,files/hdfs_logs/HDFS.log,1577982906,127,57962563,50020476
14,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-11.log,367908511,127,60836849,52344531
15,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-20.log,429342641,127,64191089,55098658
16,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-23.log,437840376,127,67611717,57912426
17,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-09.log,418434394,127,70880736,60585993
18,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-02.log,409896876,127,74083056,63201232
19,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-30.log,324151612,127,76615491,65592999
20,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-07.log,441950547,127,80068230,68440749
21,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-08.log,423204337,127,83374514,71111739
22,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-13.log,423620342,127,86684048,73820147
23,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-32.log,50871010,127,87081478,74192578
24,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-18.log,458333837,127,90662212,77156397
25,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-21.log,438525916,127,94088196,79965402
26,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-26.log,421852834,127,97383922,82661302
27,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-15.log,348380332,127,100105644,84806117
28,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-29.log,400564914,127,103235058,87346793
29,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-22.log,438617352,127,106661757,90158102
30,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-28.log,426304072,127,109992258,92878451
31,gd,files/hdfs_logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-mesos-03.log,444897046,127,113468017,95736769
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ymajorgrids,      
      xlabel=MB ingested into system,
      ylabel=MB stored in System
      ]
      \addplot table [x=iteration, y=iteration, col sep=comma,text special chars={\#}] {hdfs_logs.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use `ignore chars`, see the `pgfplotstable` manual v1.16 on p. 7:

[image]

Then you need to replace

```
\addplot table [x=iteration, y=iteration, col sep=comma,text special chars={\#}] {hdfs_logs.csv};
```

by

```
\addplot table [x=iteration, y=iteration, col sep=comma, ignore chars={\#}] {hdfs_logs.csv};
```

In the example at hand this does not make any difference because the respective columns are not used.

Comment: YOU GOT TO BE KIDDING ME... thanks a million...

Comment: @LarsNielsen You are welcome! I added two arguably more elegant solutions (and learned something new ;-).